# How do I use a double pointer to manipulate an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am running a simple program to print the first element value of an array using a double pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[3] = {1,2,3};
    int **ptr;
    *ptr = arr;
    printf("%d\n", **ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

But then I get a segmentation fault. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you dereference the pointer `ptr` in `*ptr = arr` it must already point somewhere. You're dereferencing an uninitialized pointer that doesn't point anywhere, leading to undefined behavior. Why do you need a "double pointer"? Arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element, so using plain `arr` is equal to `&arr[0]` and it has the type `int *`.

Comment: It is a test program. I was having this problem in a bigger one.

Comment: A "double pointer" is declared `double *`.  A variable of type `int **` is a pointer to pointer to int.

Comment: I'd say it still doesn't make any sense the way you use it like this (even when you make it work as in [Vlad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62176209/440558)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointer `ptr` is not initialized and has an indeterminate value.

```
int **ptr;
```

So dereferencing it results in undefined behavior.

```
*ptr = arr;
```

You need an intermediate pointer. For example

```
int *p;
int **ptr = &p;

*ptr = arr;
```

Or you could allocate the intermediate pointer dynamically like

```
int **ptr = malloc( sizeof( int * ) );
*ptr = arr;

//...
free( ptr );
```

Here are two demonstrative programs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int arr[3] = {1,2,3};
    int *p;

    int **ptr = &p;

    *ptr = arr;

    printf("%d\n", **ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

and

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    int arr[3] = {1,2,3};

    int **ptr = malloc( sizeof( int * ) );

    *ptr = arr;

    printf("%d\n", **ptr);

    free( ptr );

    return 0;
}
```

The both programs have the output

```
1
```

If you need a pointer to the whole array then its declaration can look as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    enum { N = 3 };
    int arr[N] = { 1, 2, 3 };

    int ( *ptr )[N] = &arr;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", ( *ptr )[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3
```

Comment: "Or you could allocate the intermediate pointer dynamically like `malloc( sizeof( int * ) );`: allocating memory for a single pointer doesn't make much sense, even if the program is formally correct.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Consider implementations of linked lists where this is used very often.

Comment: In a linkes list you'd have something like `malloc( sizeof( struct mystruct) )`. I really can't think of a linked list implementation where you need to allocate dynamic memory for storing a single pointer.